# Strip whitespace from strings in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, removing-whitespace

I am using python `csvkit` to compare 2 files like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('input1.csv', sep=',\s+', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8")
df2 = pd.read_csv('input2.csv', sep=',\s,', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8")
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='employee_id', how='right')
df3.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Currently I am running the file through a script before hand that strips spaces from the `employee_id` column.

An example of `employee_id`s:

```
37 78973 3
23787
2 22 3
123
```

Is there a way to get `csvkit` to do it and save me a step?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can `strip()` an entire Series in Pandas using [`.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df1['employee_id'] = df1['employee_id'].str.strip()
df2['employee_id'] = df2['employee_id'].str.strip()
```

This will remove leading/trailing whitespaces on the `employee_id` column in both `df1` and `df2`

Alternatively, modify the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) lines to use [`skipinitialspace=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#:%7E:text=variants%20of%20%E2%80%9CFalse%E2%80%9D.-,skipinitialspace,-bool%2C%20default%20False)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('input1.csv', sep=',\s+', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv('input2.csv', sep=',\s,', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
```

---

It looks like you are attempting to remove spaces in a string containing numbers, which can be accomplished with [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df1['employee_id'] = df1['employee_id'].str.replace(" ", "")
df2['employee_id'] = df2['employee_id'].str.replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 37):

You can do the `strip()` in `pandas.read_csv()` as:

```
pandas.read_csv(..., converters={'employee_id': str.strip})
```

And if you need to only strip leading whitespace:

```
pandas.read_csv(..., converters={'employee_id': str.lstrip})
```

And to remove all spaces:

```
def strip_spaces(a_str_with_spaces):
    return a_str_with_spaces.replace(' ', '')

pandas.read_csv(..., converters={'employee_id': strip_spaces})
```

Comment: Would it be pythonic if I used my own converter that either returns the result of `str.strip` or `None`? I'm importing data from Excel and it would be great if I could turn empty cells into `None` without additional steps, but I'm not sure whether this kind of _magic_ is _legal_.

Comment: dataframe cells can be None if desired.

Answer (score 11):

```
Df['employee']=Df['employee'].str.strip()
```