# How to replace similarly written values that make reference to the same (to give them the same value)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column `Cities` inside a pandas DataFrame that has a lot of words written similarly but not exactly.

For example: `"Example City"`, `" Example City"` and `"Example City "`.

This bothers me because when I look for the unique values inside the column it classifies this cities as different.

Comment: So the only difference is a trailing whitespace?

Comment: it helps to share sample data with expected output

Comment: Please provide a clear and complete description of the operation you're trying to perform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Strip white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332057/pandas-strip-white-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is just spaces at the end of the strings you can use `strip`, if you also have multiple spaces (e.g. `Example  City` and `Example City`) you can use `replace` and regex:

```
df['Cities'] = df['Cities'].str.strip()
df['Cities'] = df['Cities'].str.replace(r'\s\s+', ' ')
```

Comment: It worked for the spaces, which was the main source of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @AMC `strip()` removes white spaces both on the left and on the right, while `lstrip()` and `rstrip()` only do one side.