# Python strip method doesn't work in a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, methods, strip

I have a dataframe and one of the columns is a city name. To check if I have duplicates values I make a `df_hotels['city_name'].value_counts().sort_values`. When I display the results I can see that I have duplicates values because of an empty character on the left of some cities.[You can check that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekwe5.png). (normaly I have a count of 25 for each line)

The problem is that when I try to make a `df_hotels['city_name'] = df_hotels['city_name'].str.strip()` (or lstrip) it doesn't work, the empty character on the left is still there.

FYI a to give the context : the column type is a object and I have created the dataframe form a json with a simple pd.read_json.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Strip white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332057/pandas-strip-white-space)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `dropna` function to remove duplicate, as explained in the documetation ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)).

if you want to apply a function on a column using pandas, you need to use the apply method, and in some cases a lambda function as well. here is an example:

```
df_hotels['city_name'] = df_hotels['city_name'].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks but I don't want to drop the duplicates, I need to keep them. If I have 10 "Paris" and 15 " Paris", I want 25 "Paris". I tried the apply method but the empty space is still there...

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work for you, you are welcome to send the data set and I'll try to help.

Comment: here is the link to the csv, exported from the dataframe : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cLDetz00W4JKykPCCWvbJpSbnkVsGLI6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this will work for you:
import pandas as pd
df_hotels = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_hotels['city_name'] = df_hotels['city_name'].astype('string')                # change the type of the column
print(df_hotels.loc[df_hotels['city_name'].apply(lambda x: x.startswith(' '))]) # print where city_name starts with ' '
df_hotels['city_name'] = df_hotels['city_name'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())      # remove the ' '
print(df_hotels.loc[df_hotels['city_name'].apply(lambda x: x.startswith(' '))]) # print where city_name starts with ' '

Comment: Works perfectly ! thanks a lot @Guyblublu !