# How to justify columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The original data frame:

```
       B    C  D 
0     OE   EG  A
1     CA   EG  A
2     HA1  EG  A
3     HA2  EG  A
4  CB      EG  A
5     HB1  EG  A
```

The desired data frame:

```
       B    C  D 
0     OE   EG  A
1     CA   EG  A
2     HA1  EG  A
3     HA2  EG  A
4     CB   EG  A
5     HB1  EG  A
```

and I want to control spaces among columns!

Comment: So there are whitespaces before the values in column B?

Comment: Yes, but I think it does not matter.

Comment: It seems related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332057/pandas-strip-white-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer it is related somehow to old style format:

```
dx['A'] = dx['A'].map('{:6s}'.format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str_cols = df.select_dtype('object')
df[str_cols.columns] = str_cols.apply(lambda col: col.str.strip())
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'select_dtype'